# Go to another view by clicking a button in Custom Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, uicollectionviewcell

I created the custom cell (XIB) as the subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` and the cell has a button in it. When I click a button, I want to go to another view with some data on that, and could go back to the original view by clicking a button as well. I've search for that and found something like "segue" or "modal" but I can't do it initially from my custom cell.

Is there any way to do this? Any help would be very thankful.

Comment: What is your problem? Add some property to your cell that provides you with all the information you need to launch the new view and launch it. 
And yes, you may present it modally or you can push the view controller to your navigation controller or you can use a segue from a storyboard.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I've using no storyboard, only XIB. There is no "Trigger segues" as storyboard.

Comment: Well, then you cannot use a segue.There are still two options left.

Comment: @user1967709 yeah just like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you want to do, since it seems like UICollectionView works the same as UITableView, is make a subclass of UICollectionViewCell that contains a **protocol** to send actions, like pressing a button, to a view controller from a different view. In this case, a different view being the UICollectionViewCell.

### Adding a Protocol to a UICollectionViewCell

Add a new **Cocoa Touch Class** called **UICustomCollectionViewCell** with subclass of **UICollectionViewCell**. And include the **interface builder file**

**header file UICustomCollectionViewCell.h**

```
@protocol UICustomCollectionViewCellDelegate;

@interface UICustomCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property ( nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
- (IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender;

@property ( assign) id< UICustomCollectionViewCellDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol UICustomCollectionViewCellDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)customCollectionViewCell:(UICustomCollectionViewCell *)cell pressedButton:(UIButton *)button;

@end
```

**implementation file UICustomCollectionViewCell.m**

```
@implementation UICustomCollectionViewCell
@synthesize delegate;

- (IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender {
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector: @selector( customCollectionViewCell:pressedButton:)])
        [delegate customCollectionViewCell: self pressedButton: sender];

}

@end
```

**xib file UICustomCollectionViewCell.xib**

make sure the connections from the **UICustomCollectionViewCell** are connected to the button from the **Connections Inspector**:

1. button
2. -pressButton:

[image: example]

**Finally, using this class in your project**

Import the class as well as the delegate:

```
#import "UICustomCollectionViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController () < UICustomCollectionViewCellDelegate>

@end
```

In this following code, you will use the **UICustomCollectionViewCell** class instead of **UICollectionViewCell**:

```
UICustomCollectionViewCell *cell;

...
[cell setDelegate: self];
...

return cell;
```

And now the action, or method, that is called when the button is pressed:

```
- (void)customCollectionViewCell:(UICustomCollectionViewCell *)cell pressedButton:(UIButton *)button {
    //action will be here when the button is pressed

}
```

If you want to find out what indexPath this cell was from:

```
[collectionView indexPathForCell: cell];
```

Comment: please do ask for any explanation of any of this. i'm happy to reply right away :)

Comment: I've seen you answers, now trying, will reply if it works. :)

Comment: I wonder if new view required to be subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` and how to go to that view, using `presentViewController` didn't work.

Comment: When you mean by "new view" are you trying to present this "new view" as a view controller? Not sure what you're trying to present

Comment: Yes, I want to put my "new view" some stuff. I actually want to jump from the main page of my app to the page which like "Settings".

Comment: Ooh okay. You will have to create a subclass of UIViewController. Like when we created a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` and called it `UICustomCollectionViewCell` Makes sense? Here's an example of what I believe you're trying to get to pass data between view controllers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5210535/1967709 Is this what you mean??

Comment: Btw did the code work? Did the app get to the code: `- (void)customCollectionViewCell:(UICustomCollectionViewCell *)cell pressedButton:(UIButton *)button {     //action will be here when the button is pressed  }`

Comment: Build failed T^T Cannot find protocol declaration

Comment: Did you have this in your header file of the UICustomCollectiomViewCell: `@protocol UICustomCollectionViewCellDelegate;` and `@protocol UICustomCollectionViewCellDelegate <NSObject>` the two names has to be exactly the same. Where is this error pointing at? Like which file? Your view controller or the cell class?

Comment: I created the custom cell before so I just used its name but did make sure the name are the same. I've import the custom cell.h yet the error occurs in ViewController. It seems like it doesn't know the delegate.

Comment: Sounds like it should all work. Is the protocol name exactly the same as the class name? I'm making sure that the only difference between the protocol name and the class name is the protocol has **Delegate** at the end of the name

Comment: Oh! I just noticed that my initial controller is UICollectionView! Could the protocol be applied to this?

Comment: I just delete the point which error occurred and it worked to the method you mentioned. (//action will be here when the button is pressed). Light of hope comes O.O What now? I'm trying something in the link you sent but still got some confusion.

Comment: That's good, I don't believe you can just add a methods to an existing class. You would have to subclass it, which is what we did, to add your own protocol. I'm assuming by removing the code with the error you're getting a warning pointing to `[cell setDelegate: self];` ? But I am glad this worked! :D

Comment: What's next is you said you wanted to send data from this first view controller to the next, the view controller you're presenting when the button is pressed?

Comment: That point got Warning but still run fine. Actually, It doesn't matter what controller of the next one should be (to get the easiest solution), as long as it could switch my view to another as the button pressed.

Comment: Right it will run just had those warnings and without that line of code, you'll have to copy and paste the methods from the protocol we made, if there was more you wanted to use/make.

Comment: Well you'd want to make a new class called **SettingsViewController** and also **include xib file**. Then import this new class to the **implementation file** of your main view controller then paste this code where the action is when button is pressed: `SettingsViewController *viewSettings = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"SettingsViewController" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];` this will allocate your new view controller. Then paste this in the next line: `[self presentViewController: viewSettings animated: YES completion: ^{ }];` and then this will present the settings

Comment: neato! :D glad to have helped out, takes some time to understand what the question is but happy to have succeeded :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't/shouldn't perform navigation jobs in the cell, navigation is not in the cells domain.

What you can try is

1) Use a delegate, setup a delegate and wire it up to the button action, the controller hosting the tableview/collection view can set itself up as the delegate and listen to any events. This controller should be in charge of pushing a new view to the stack using any method you desire.

2) If you hate delegates but love blocks, you can setup a callback block on the cell, its actions could be setup in the cellForRowAtIndex: method in the controller.

Noticed a pattern here? both the above methods are delegating the task from the cell to the controller.

If all fails, just implement `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` and stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with didSelect method?

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

YourNewViewControllerClass *someViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourNewVCID"];

[self presentViewController:someViewController
                     animated:YES
                   completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to implement `cellForRow..` method, set a tag for your cell/button and react basing on that tag (eg. `indexPath.row`).

Answer (score 0):

1.custom your button

NouMapButton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NouMapButton : UIButton 
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSObject *dataObj;
@end
```

NouMapButton.m

```
#import "NouMapButton.h"
@implementation NouMapButton
@end
```

2. set your button data and target in

   ```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

   btn01.dataObj = YOUR_DATA;
   [btn01 addTarget:self action:@selector(map:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   ```
3. then you can get button custom dataObj in sender.dataObj

   ```
   -(void)map:(NouMapButton *)sender{
       MapViewController *nextView = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
       nextView.dataObj = sender.dataObj;
       //TODO....


   }
   ```